# What was the crysistor?

Tags: computers

I'm reading through Jim Williams' "Analog Circuit Design: Art, Science and Personalities", and a mysterious component called a crysistor is mentioned. There are a few clues in the text, like the fact that it was a superconducting magnetic memory that "showed promise of revolutionizing the computer world". I can't find any reference to the crysistor aside from this book. What was the crysistor and how did it work?

Comment: I have heard of components called [memristors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memristor) that somewhat fits your description. But I haven't heard of "crysistors" as such.

Comment: I assume cry-sistor is a cryogenic resistor.  Maybe a Squid?  (That's at least super conductiong and magnetic.)

Comment: That's a good guess, considering SQUIDs were invented in 1964-1965. I'm not sure how old the author of that chapter (Samuel Wilensky) was at the time, but it seems plausible.

Comment: I heard there was an effort to make computers with Josephson jucntions at IBM..http://www.w2agz.com/Library/Superconductivity/Anacker,%20IBM%20Josephson%20Project%20IBMJ.Res.Dev.24-2-107-112.pdf

Comment: This IEEE pdf briefly mentions it in an article about Cryosistors.   Page 353 (4th of pdf) in the Figure 1 text it uses Crysistor by name.  Can't tell from the text if it's saying you make a Cryosistor from a Crysistor?  http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=4066276

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it might have been the conflation of *[cryosistor](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/ielx5/10933/4066234/04066276.pdf?tp=&arnumber=4066276&isnumber=4066234)* (a completely different germanium cryogenic unijunction-like device that worked on the principle of impact ionization) and *[crytron](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5392695)* (not to be confused with the [*krytron*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krytron) which is used to make loud noises).

---

I think he was referring specifically to the **crytron** and got the name mixed up a bit in his memory.

---

The chapter is not error-free (for example, it refers to "new low-temperature superconductors" which would not be an advantage, especially compared to liquid helium).

Here is the actual quote, courtesy of Google books:

[image]

The IBM paper describing the crytron which I linked above was published in October of 1957, so it would have been fresh news in 1959 when Mr. Wilensky graduated.

Comment: I love those names. Although my favorite -tron device is the carcinotron, because it just sounds diabolical.

Comment: @aloishis89 LOL. It looks pretty [diabolical](http://www.technologymuseum.eu/phpwebgallery/galleries/Composants/Actifs_tubes/Carcinotron_Thomson_CSF_F_4029_E.jpg) too!

Comment: Nice, I think he just forgot the -o-.  Re: the cryosistor, Thanks for the cyrosistor link!  (I'll note that they used indium to make  an alloyed p-n junction in Ge.  +1 just for that!)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I don't think so. The cryosistor is completely different. Mr. Wilensky described what he heard about as a "superconducting magnetic memory". I think it was the crytron, which fits the time frame and the description is the same. The cryosistor was a bit too late, I think (1960 and he graduated in '59).

Comment: Spehro, OK fair enough.  (And just to muddy the already murky waters what about the cryotron?    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryotron (maybe the same thing but GE added the -o- and IBM didn't.)